# How to change view of google map

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to set google map view according to my needs but unable to do. Actually I want to show google map like this

[image]

But it is showing like this

[image]
I am using this code:

```
function init_map() {
    var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(33.6934473,35.644258);

    var var_mapoptions = {
      center: var_location,
      zoom: 12
    };

    var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: var_location,
        map: var_map,
        title:"Venice"});

    var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
        var_mapoptions);

    var_marker.setMap(var_map); 

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the center of the map to a different location than the marker.

```js
function init_map() {
  var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(33.6934473, 35.644258);

  var var_mapoptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.691578, 35.523065),
    zoom: 12
  };

  var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: var_location,
    map: var_map,
    title: "Venice"
  });

  var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
    var_mapoptions);

  var_marker.setMap(var_map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="map-container"></div>
```